# Xamarin Forms & Prism on iOS Navigation Bar is double height

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, uinavigationbar, prism

I've encountered an issue with the navigation bar height in the iOS version of my Xamarin Forms Prism app whereby it appears to be double height.

It displays correctly on Android.

I navigate to the page in the normal Prism way (ViewDaily is a Detail of the MasterDetailPage MainPage):

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/NavigationPage/ViewDaily");
```

But the same also happens if I navigate to as a normal Navigation Page. This isn't my use case as I need the MasterDetail Page but i tried as a test:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationPage/ViewDaily");
```

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dan Siegel for the answer:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/2511

Add the following to the Detail (Content) Page:

ios:Page.LargeTitleDisplay="Never"

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `ViewDaily` only, otherwise you add *another* navigation page...

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("ViewDaily");
```

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for the reply. My use case is that I need to ViewDaily to be a Detail Page of MainPage. I only tested the navigating to ViewDaily as a NavigationPage to see if the NavigationBar is double height still, and it is.